# How can I access files from a Google Cloud Storage bucket from a browser?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Cloud Storage to store images for my Google App Engine application and I'm trying to access the images like so:

```
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/IMAGE_NAME">
```

However, this displays "Access Denied" or presents me with a Google login prompt.
Then I tried using [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) to grant the client access.

I generated the URL to be signed like so:

```
String HTTP_Verb = "GET";
String Expiration = "1361993085";
String Canonicalized_Resource = "/bucket_name/sub_directory";
String stringToSign = HTTP_Verb + "\n" + Expiration + "\n" + Canonicalized_Resource;
```

And then generated Base64 with the p12 file and compiled using Java, but I got this error:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there way I can access images from GCS without authentication?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

And finally after 2 days, got it working.here is the answer:
My approach for this is **wrong**, no need for signed URL. i need to just add my bucket as **public-read** so that i can read it from browser request. thats all.
open gsutil, type this:

```
gsutil -m acl -r set public-read gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

and set this as default for all future uploads

```
gsutil -m defacl set public-read gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

hope it helps someone !

Thanks to @kctang !

Comment: No need `.py` if gsutll is set on PATH:    
=> `gsutil -m defacl set public-read gs://BUCKET_NAME`    
=> `gsutil -m acl set -R -a public-read gs://BUCKET_NAME`

Comment: We need also to enter an authorized id or email for the groups and users and a domain for the domains for the [bucket permission](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_bucketpermission) otherwise you will get an error message like: `'DefAclCommand' object has no attribute 'continue_on_error'`

Answer (score 9):

`gsutil` has been updated and you now need to do:

```
gsutil -m acl -r set public-read gs://bucket-name
gsutil -m defacl set public-read gs://bucket-name
```

P.S. For people unfamiliar with `gsutil`, [here is how to install it](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install).

Answer (score 9):

For a more general answer, the way to access an gs:// url is to use this format:

`https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/[BUCKET_NAME]/`

For example, if the bucket you're trying to access is the Landsat public dataset,`gs://gcp-public-data-landsat/` then you'd access the bucket with this url: `https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/gcp-public-data-landsat/`

Here's the documentation related to accessing a bucket:

1. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data
2. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the content-md5 and content-type fields in the [string to be signed](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Construct-the-String). They can be blank, but you still need `\n` separators. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17508285/624900) for a working example of constructing the string to sign.