# How to download an object from google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I uploaded a CSV file `test.csv` to Google Cloud Storage's bucket. The resulting `public_url` is like this

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/test-2017-04-11-025727.csv
```

Originally `test.csv' has some row and column containing numbers like this

```
6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1 
8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1
...
...
```

I uploaded the file by referring to bookshelf tutorial --> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python no `6-pubsub`. The uploaded file will be saved with timestamp added to it.

Now I want to download the file that I uploaded to the bucket by using `requests`

Here is what I've been working on. The original sample is at `6-pubsub/bookshelf/crud.py`. Below is script that I already edited based on the original sample.

```
from machinelearning import get_model, oauth2, storage, tasks
from flask import Blueprint, current_app, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for

import requests
import os

...
...

crud = Blueprint('crud', __name__)

save_folder = 'temp/'

def upload_csv_file(file):
    ...
    ...
    return public_url

...
...
@crud.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def add():
    data = request.form.to_dict(flat=True)

    # This will upload the file that I pushed from local directory to GCS

    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_url = upload_csv_file(request.files.get('file'))

        if csv_url:
            data['csvUrl'] = csv_url

    # I think this is not working. This should download back the file and save it to a temporary folder inside current working directory

    response = requests.get(public_url)
    if not os.path.exists(save_folder):
        os.makedirs(save_folder)

    with open(save_folder + 'testdata.csv', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)

    ...
    ...
```

I opened folder `temp` and check the `testdata.csv`. It shows me an error like this inside the CSV file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object mybucket/test-2017-04-11-025727.csv.</Details></Error>
```

I was hoping `testdata.csv` will have same contents like `test.csv` but it did not.

I already recheck my OAuth client and secret, bucket id on `config.py` but the error still there.

How do I solve this kind of error?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: It sounds like your object is not publicly accessible. You'll want to mark it as publicly readable, either in the console or by setting the ACL when you upload it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It is just like mr @Brandon Yarbrough said that the bucket's object is not publicly readable.

To make the bucket public, taking from this link --> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/419

```
gsutil defacl set public-read gs://<bucket_name>
```

Comment: See an updated answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20162788/948942